# Laravel 5.4 - Updating a resource

Tags: laravel, crud, laravel-5.4

I'm building a blog post to learn Laravel 5.4 and am struggling to find any examples of how to update a Post anywhere.

My form is as follows

```html
<form method="POST" action="/posts/{{ $post->id }}/edit">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input name="title" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value="{{ $post->title }}" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <input name="description" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" value="{{ $post->title }}" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My Routes are as follows

```php
Route::get('/posts/{post}/edit', 'PostsController@edit');

Route::patch('/posts/{post}', 'PostsController@update');
```

And my controller methods are

```php
public function edit( Post $post )
{
    return view('posts.edit', compact('post'));
}

public function update(Request $request, Post $post )
{
    Post::where('id', $post)->update($request->all());

    return redirect('home');

}
```

I get a `MethodNotAllowedHTTPException` error but am not sure which part / parts of this I am getting wrong.

I'm assuming it must be the point at which I'm using the PATCH function, or potentially just the way I'm mass-assigning the new values. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should add `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">` to your form.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you should use

```
{{ method_field('PATCH') }}
```

as your form field

and change action to

```
/posts/{{ $post->id }}
```

like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="/posts/{{ $post->id }}">

        {{ csrf_field() }}
{{ method_field('PATCH') }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input name="title" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value="{{ $post->title }}" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">Description</label>
            <input name="description" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" value="{{ $post->title }}" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>

        </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! Is there something wrong with my controller update function also? Just got 'method update does not exist' error after these changes

Comment: @helenkitt That might be because in the controller you're using `$request->all();` so it's trying to update CSRF token fields on the table which don't exist.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of things you have missed out.

Firstly, as @Maraboc pointed out in the comments you need to add method spoofing as standard HTML forms only allow for `GET` and `POST` methods:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
```

or

```
{{ method_field('PATCH') }}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#form-method-spoofing

Then you will also need to omit the "edit" uri in your forms action:

```
<form method="POST" action="/posts/{{ $post->id }}">
```

or

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('posts/' . $post->id) }}">
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers

(scroll down a little bit to the **Actions Handled By Resource Controller** section)

You also may find it helpful to watch https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/10

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

When building an API, you may need a transformation layer that sits between your Eloquent models and the JSON responses that are actually returned to your application's users. Laravel's resource classes allow you to expressively and easily transform your models and model collections into JSON.